# How to shrink text and center vertically in a line defined by larger text

Tags: footnotes, text

I'm trying to number sections of a document. I want the numbers to appear inline but not as super or subscripts. I want them to print in the middle of the line, but in a smaller print, like the multiplication symbol does here: `2⋅2`. See how the multiplication symbol is directly in the middle of the two.

Comment: that dot is not raised it is just that the character has white space under the . however perhaps you are looking for  `\raisebox{3pt}{\footnotesize hello}` but it is hard to tell what you mean, you tagged the question footnotes but the question doesn't mention footnotes, just section numbers?

Comment: some sketch what you like to have and document example (mwe: minimal working example) with what you try so far will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

David Carlisle has the answer: `\raisebox{1pt}` is precisely what I was looking for.